# Struts Error: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found

Tags: java, struts

```
The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
        at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.TagUtils.getStack(TagUtils.java:60)
        at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.StrutsBodyTagSupport.getStack(StrutsBodyTagSupport.java:44)
        at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:48)
        at jsp_servlet.__login._jsp__tag0(__login.java:115)
        at jsp_servlet.__login._jspService(__login.java:84)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:408)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:318)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3495)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The stack trace seems to confirm what the exception message explains : you probably try to render the login.jsp page, and this JSP uses some struts tag. But since the request has not gone through the Struts filter, the tag can't work.

In Struts (and every other action-based framework AFAIK), every URL (except for static resources like images, scripts, etc) should point to the cebtral servlet or filter, which dispatches to your action, which itself forwards to a JSP. If you invoke the JSP directly, it isn't MVC anymore, and the tags can't work.